# Prevent click on label from triggering child button

Tags: javascript, html

When setup like this, clicking on a label that has a child button triggers button's onclick event:

```js
function fireButton() {
  console.log("Button fired!");
}
```

```html
<label>Label
  <button onclick="fireButton()">Button</button>
</label>
```

is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: That is just a pattern you should avoid to begin with; common accessibility guidelines explicitly advise against nesting such interactive elements which have their own functionality into labels.

Comment: granted.. I'll work on a better design in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add for attribute to label.

```js
function fireButton() {
  console.log("Button fired!");
}
```

```html
<label for=''>Label
  <button onclick="fireButton()">Button</button>
</label>
```

Comment: For attribute associate with Id of its descendant. if you don't want want to associate it then set it blank.

Comment: This did it for me! Simple and effective use of builtin functionality, even if my design is poor and deserves refactoring as stated by @CBroe in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803356/prevent-click-on-label-from-triggering-child-button#comment114575501_64803356

Comment: You design it well to  elaborate the issue. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can put the button outside the label

```
<label>Label</label>
<button onclick="fireButton()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add preventDefault for labels and keep the existing code:

```
document.querySelector("label").addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different tag e.g `<span>` rather than the `label` But if you really need to use the `<label>`, you should prevent the default behaviour of the label `onclick()` like so:

```js
function fireButton(){
//add actions here
}

function preventDefault(event){
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<label onclick="preventDefault(event)">Label
  <button onclick="fireButton()">Button</button>
</label>
```

Comment: I could add that line in the body of fireButton() if I passed the event on too, right?

Comment: No, Adding it to the ```fireButton()``` won't be affecting the behaviour of the label. Which means that the button click will still be triggered when you click the label. So it has to be on the label's click event @GugaFigueiredo

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach in CSS which also disables triggering `button`'s `:active` state when clicking on `label`. Overriding `label`'s `onClick` event does not do that.

```css
label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
    
button {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```